# Front End submission with meta key

Tags: custom-post-types

I'm working to create a front end custom post type submission from. I already coded checking different tuto. But the form returned not found page upon suvmission, again not inputing any data. Please help me to find out the error if possible.

```
<?php
if (!isset($_POST['submit'])) {

?>
<form method="post" action="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">

    <table>

        <tr><th width="138"><label for="id_meta">Mobile No:</label></th><td width="163"><input id="id_meta" type="text" name="wpcf-mob_no" maxlength="100" /></td></tr>

        <tr><th width="138"><label for="id_meta">Amount To Load:</label></th><td width="163"><input id="id_meta" type="text" name="wpcf-mob_amount" maxlength="100" /></td></tr>

        <tr><th width="138"><label for="id_meta">Connection Type</label></th><td width="163"><select id="id_meta" type="text" name="wpcf-mob_type" maxlength="100" />
          <option value="pre_paid">Pre Paid</option>
          <option value="post_paid">Post Paid</option>
        </td></tr>

        <tr><th width="138"></th><td width="163"><input id="id_meta" type="hidden" name="wpcf-mob_status" maxlength="100" value="pending"/></td></tr>

        <tr><th></th><td><input id="id_title" type="hidden" name="post_title" maxlength="100" value="<?php echo date('r'); ?>"/></td></tr>


        <tr>

            <td>&nbsp;</td>
<input type="hidden" name="post_type" id="post_type" value="loads" />

<input type="hidden" name="action" value="post" />

<?php wp_nonce_field( 'new-post' ); ?>

            <td><input type="submit" value="Submit" name="submit"/></td>

        </tr>

    </table>



</form>

<?php }

else {

        $title = $_POST['post_title'];
        $meta_box1 = $_POST['wpcf-mob_no'];
        $meta_box2 = $_POST['wpcf-mob_amount'];
        $meta_box3 = $_POST['wpcf-mob_type'];
        $meta_box4 = $_POST['wpcf-mob_status'];

        $new_post = array(
            'post_title'    => $title,
            'post_status'   => 'publish',           // Choose: publish, preview, future, draft, etc.
            'post_type' => 'loads'  //'post',page' or use a custom post type if you want to
    );
    //save the new post
    $pid = wp_insert_post($new_post);

    /* Insert Form data into Custom Fields */
    add_post_meta($pid, 'wpcf-mob_no', $meta_box1, true);
    add_post_meta($pid, 'wpcf-mob_amount', $meta_box2, true);
    add_post_meta($pid, 'wpcf-mob_type', $meta_box3, true);
    add_post_meta($pid, 'wpcf-mob_status', $meta_box4, true);


    print '<pre>';
    var_dump(array($new_post, $pid));
    print '</pre>';
}

?>
```

Comment: just leave the action field empty if you sending data to the same page.

Comment: Why not use XHR for the form submission? http://codex.wordpress.org/AJAX_in_Plugins

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the meta data field is already there you should update it.
also you should time the wp_insert_post... here is the revied code

try it and let me know it you encounter problems:

```
else {

        $title = $_POST['post_title'];
        $meta_box1 = $_POST['wpcf-mob_no'];
        $meta_box2 = $_POST['wpcf-mob_amount'];
        $meta_box3 = $_POST['wpcf-mob_type'];
        $meta_box4 = $_POST['wpcf-mob_status'];

        $new_post = array(
            'post_title'    => $title,
            'post_status'   => 'publish',           // Choose: publish, preview, future, draft, etc.
            'post_type' => 'loads'  //'post',page' or use a custom post type if you want to
    );
    //save the new post
    $pid    =   wp_insert_post($new_post, 10, 1);

    // Do the wp_insert_post action to insert it
    do_action('wp_insert_post', 'wp_insert_post', 10, 1); 
    update_metadata($pid, 'wpcf-mob_no', $meta_box1, true);
    update_metadata($pid, 'wpcf-mob_amount', $meta_box2, true);
    update_metadata($pid, 'wpcf-mob_type', $meta_box3, true);
    update_metadata($pid, 'wpcf-mob_status', $meta_box4, true);


    print '<pre>';
    var_dump(array($new_post, $pid));
    print '</pre>';
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The code bellow worked for me.

```
add_post_meta($pid, 'wpcf-mob_no', $meta_box1, true);
add_post_meta($pid, 'wpcf-mob_amount', $meta_box2, true);
add_post_meta($pid, 'wpcf-mob_type', $meta_box3, true);
add_post_meta($pid, 'wpcf-mob_status', $meta_box4, true);
```